# Supress MEX warning: f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory ‘MATLABROO​T/simulink​/include’ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]

Tags: matlab, fortran, gfortran, mex

I have MATLAB 2019b but not simulink installed on my computer (ubuntu 16.04). When trying

```
mex(fullfile(matlabroot, 'extern', 'examples', 'refbook', 'timestwo.F'));
```

I got the following

```
warning: f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory 'MATLABROOT/simulink/include' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
```

where MATLABROOT represents the root path of matlab on my computer. Nevertheless, the resultant timestwo.mexa64 works without any problem. I suppose simulink is not needed at all for timestwo.
I am writing a script for mexifying a few Fortran functions of my own, and the same warning pops up inevitably. However, my functions do not rely on simulink in any way. **How can I suppress this warning?**

Thank you very much!

---

In case needed (even though not likely), here is the output of mex -v -setup FORTRAN. It containts nothing strange and nothing related to simulink.

```
Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'gfortran6-' ...
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Looking for folder '/usr/bin' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Executing command 'gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortran.so' ...Yes ('/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.so').
... Looking for folder '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Executing command 'gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortranbegin.a' ...Yes ('/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortranbegin.a').
... Looking for folder '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Executing command 'gfortran -dumpversion' ...Yes ('5.5.0').
Found installed compiler 'gfortran6-'.
... Looking for compiler 'gfortran' ...
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Looking for folder '/usr/bin' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Executing command 'gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortran.so' ...Yes ('/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.so').
... Looking for folder '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Executing command 'gfortran -dumpversion | awk -F '.' '$1>=6' ' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'gfortran'.
... Looking for compiler 'gfortran6-' ...
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Looking for folder '/usr/bin' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Executing command 'gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortran.so' ...Yes ('/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.so').
... Looking for folder '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Executing command 'gfortran -print-file-name=libgfortranbegin.a' ...Yes ('/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortranbegin.a').
... Looking for folder '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which gfortran' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/gfortran').
... Executing command 'gfortran -dumpversion' ...Yes ('5.5.0').
Found installed compiler 'gfortran6-'.
MEX configured to use 'gfortran6-' for FORTRAN language compilation.
```

Comment: Add `-v` to your `mex` call: `mex('-v', fullfile(...))`. This will output all the compile and link commands, you'll be able to see where this error message comes from.

Comment: Thank you, @CrisLuengo, for the comment.

Comment: Ok, but did you do it? What are the compiler and linker commands? Please share them with us so we can help you figure out how to get rid of the warning. I suggest you include also the list of variable definitions that it will output.

Comment: In fact the problem is not how to "get rid of" the warning, but how to "suppress" the warning (i.e., the warning is generated, but it will not be printed on the screen). I know that the warning is because Simulink is missing (more precisely, $MATLABROOT/simulink/include is missing). To get rid of it, I can simply make an empty directory $MATLABROOT/simulink/include. Thank you.

Comment: Since you don't use Simulink, `mex` shouldn't be looking for its directory at all. I assumed there is something wrong with your setup that might need fixing. If all you want to do is suppress the warning message, the warning message tells you how to do it: it is `-Wmissing-include-dirs` that generates the warning, so adding `-Wno-missing-include-dirs` to your compiler flags will prevent it from being generated.

Comment: @CrisLuengo there seems to be a bug in gfortran preventing this flag from working: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55534